# how to use d3 to scroll whole page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I want my d3 to be able to scroll whole page while it pan.

kinda like the [effect on challonge](http://challonge.com/tournaments/bracket_generator?ref=OQS06q7I5u),but only on the y axis.

This is my attempt to do it.

```
pan.call(d3.drag().on("drag", function dragged() {
        // x axis
        thisPosX += d3.event.dx;
        g.attr("transform", "translate(" + thisPosX + ", 0)");
        g1.attr("transform", "translate(" + thisPosX + ", 0)");
        position.x = thisPosX;
        // y axis.
        var tmp = d3.event.dy;
        if (tmp != -lastTmp) {
            $window.scrollTo(0, $window.scrollY - tmp);
            lastTmp = tmp;
        }
}));
```

But this code still makes the panning very laggy and have some spikes.

Is there any better ways to do it?btw, I'm using angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do doesn't require d3. Sure, you can bind events with d3 but the drag behaviour is designed to drag elements inside a container such as canvas or svg, which is static.

I found this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/rkofB) that might do the work.

First, I advise you to wrap you svg in a div that will have the drag behaviour, that what Challonge did if you look into its source code:
[image]

Then define a scroll on drag behaviour, I have adapted the previous codepen to use d3:

```
var curYPos = 0;
var curDown = false;

var scrollable = d3.select('#scrollable');
scrollable.on('mousemove', function () {
  // Scroll only if mouse is down
  if (curDown === true){
    // Scroll only along Y
    // d3.mouse(this) is the position of the cursor inside your scrollable (this)
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollTop + (curYPos - d3.mouse(this)[1]));
  }
});

scrollable.on('mousedown', function () {
  curDown = true;
  curYPos = d3.mouse(this)[1];
});
scrollable.on('mouseup mouseleave', function () {
  curDown = false;
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObvVpL)

Comment: this code has a bug, that if your mouse leaves the dragging area, the page will scroll back to top.

Comment: I think it's not that hard to debug!

Comment: yes, i debugged it, combining d3.mouse and d3.drag.on fixed the issue, thank you.